# Does wocoomerce taking the payment from user when admin delete refund?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Woocommerce is already having refund functionality along with delete refund functionality.

When admin is giving the refund at that time user will get the refund according to the choice selected by admin after giving the refund there is an option of delete refund. Why it is really required? What happens when admin deleted refund? Does payment gateway  taking the payment with user again?

I am fighting here with delete refund concept what happen if refund is deleted from admin ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete refund functionality just deletes the refunded amount from the order statically, it does not take back the refunded amount from the user. It is just for the admin who wants to modify the order total by deleting the refund.
Payment gateway cannot take back the refunded amount back from the user.